# Terminal Services Servers Information

Tags: terminal-services

I was wondering if anyone had some good general information on windows terminal services and how it works.
I'm wondering:

- If a DLL is loaded into memory is it available for all users or reloaded for each user. (or does it depend on something else)
- A specification for an example server and how many concurrent users it supports with general use....
- Any issues with them, I used one a while ago and we had sporadic freezes for a few seconds every so often. This could not be tracked down to a network issue someone suggested something to do with remote printers being attached to the system. It really annoyed users seemed to happen often when going to the start menu.
- Is 2008 a big upgrade in terms of performance to 2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminal Services is simply like a server with multiple "remote desktop".

- DLL is not shared between sessions, just like ordinal process.
- You need a special license if you want to use standard Windows server
- I suggest removing all the printers when you want to use it (you can also disable them in client side), but that's not a big issue
- 2008 is far better for performance and security, but you'd also need more recent RDP clients.

Comment: Is that printers thing a real issue? Is that in fact a possibility for the freeze's

Comment: The problem is the sharing/discovery process in Windows. It is sometimes very slow and freezing entire system (due to I/O pending state).

In fact you can also find windows to stuck in network domains when exploring other computers - and if you disable the printer discovering it will be faster.